# Where to get new trained classifier cascade type for detectMultiScale call?

Tags: c++, opencv, face-detection

For a presentation I want to show the OpenCV ability to do with few commands a face recognition. Inside the detectMultiScale call there is a test

```
if( isOldFormatCascade() )
{
```

which is always true for all "xml" files coming with the OpenCV library. Where can I get a new version of the trained cascade files?

I know there is a tool for that called "opencv_traincascade", but I am short on time and want to avoid the training. As I only need a simple face recognition I hope there are already some files out htere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's more cascades [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/data)

opencv_traincascade writes files in the 'new' format (lbp and hog supported, too), opencv_haartraining in the old( haar only ).

(and it does not matter, if it's xml or yml)

so the lbpcascades and the hogcascades in the the link above are in the new format, the haar ones in the old.

if you're looking for faces, there are lbpcascades for that, too (much faster, but not as accurate as haar).